# Syntaxhighlighter evolved 3.1.1 and Wordpress 3.1.3

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I am not able to post any kind of formatted code into a post using the integrated editor in WordPress. I have checked and my theme's footer.php has the wp_footer command as requested on the Syntaxhighlighter evolved FAQ.
Furthermore it seems so obvious how to mark the code, but there is no easy step by stepinstruction on where I have to put the [php] [/php] tags; inside the visual editor? or the HTML editor? 
I am quite new to wordpress, so I I have not worked with those short commands before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML view of your post, just wrap your code in the [php] and [/PHP] tags, and it will auto-format it. Because you're using special brackets ("[" and "]") and not the standard brackets, it allows the highlighter to see them and format properly.